# SSLSocket enabledProtocols does not return tls v1.2

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, sslsocketfactory, sslcontext

I am testing on Android 4.2.2 (API 17) and running following code.

```
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = .... //generating KeyManagerFactory
        if (kmf == null) {
            throw new UnexpectedInternalException("Initialisation of SSLContext failed!");
        }
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
        SSLSocketFactory f = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

and when I inspect the SocketFactory, I see below:

[image]
Why does it not show `TLSv1.2`?

I run the same code on Android 6.0 and it does return `TLSv1.2`. According to SSLContext API docs, `TLSv1.2` is supported from API 16+ and Android 4.2.2 is API 17. It should return `TLSv1.2` but not sure why it is not returning in the `enabledProtocols`.